# center-of-gravity class for a Java program

Tags: java, math

I will probably have to implement a center-of-gravity class but I will ask help in seeking such a Java class before I do.  I suspect this has been implemented by others as part of a math library.

In a space of n-dimensions, suppose each dimension is discrete.  So for example in 3 dimensions, you can have an X dimension with a range of `[0..a]`.  You also have a Y dimension with a range of `[0..b]` and a Z dimension with a range of `[0..c]`.  The implementation should be general so that the number of dimensions can be greater than 3 and also generally `a not equal to b` where `a` and `b` are the maximum coordinates of their respective dimensions.

Each point in the space is a double precision float (non-negative).

Find the coordinate of the center-of-gravity.

Comment: If homework, please tag as such.

Comment: Well I work at home but it isn't homework.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a physics engine, you can easily get the centre of gravity -- try [JBullet](http://jbullet.advel.cz/) :) The centre of mass which you can get with the API is essentially the same thing, but with a slight difference:

> The term center of mass is often used interchangeably with center of
>   gravity, but they are physically different concepts. They happen to
>   coincide in a uniform gravitational field, but where gravity is not
>   uniform, center of gravity refers to the mean location of the
>   gravitational force acting on a body. This results in small but
>   measurable gravitational torque that must be accounted for in the
>   operation of artificial satellites.

http://www.continuousphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtRigidBody.html